# Help to find the probability of being selected as a winning an entry in a raffle where people get multiple entries

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

56 total entries in a raffle with 3 winners. Only 35 people participating, and a winner can't be chosen more than once. I have 2 of the 56 entries.
6 other people have 2 entries.
2 people have 3 entries.
2 people have 4 entries.
1 person has 5 entries.
23 people only have one entry.

What are my chances of being selected as one of the winners taking into account the rule that a person can't be chosen for more than 1 entry?

Comment: count all triplets (remember to count permutations) * probability of choosing this triplet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the probability $P$ of you being selected by using $P = 1-\bar{P}$, where $\bar{P}$ is the probability that you are not being selected.

For the first round, we have $\bar{P}_1 = \frac{54}{56}$. The second round is more complicated, as we don't know the number of entries remaining. I don't see any other way than doing this the hard way:
With probability $\frac{23}{54}$ we have 53 entries remaining (excluding yours - this is for the case that one of the people with one entry has been selected), with probability $\frac{12}{54}$ we have 52 entries remaining and so on. The probability of you not being selected after round two would then be $\bar{P}_2 = \bar{P}_1 \times \left(\frac{23}{54} \times \frac{53}{55} + \frac{12}{54} \times \frac{52}{54} + ...\right)$. You need to do similar calculations for one more round. This is tedious work but should give you the correct result.